# Please blacklist the [jasperviewer] & [jasperprint] tags

Tags: discussion, blocklist-request

The questions under this tags are about using *JasperReports Java API*.

*JasperViewer* and *JasperPrint* are classes from *JasperReports* library.

Instead of this two tags the combination of [jasper-reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasper-reports) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tags should be used.

---

<sup>P.S.</sup>
<sup>Some times ago one guy added *[jasperprint]* tag to ***50*** posts (yes, you are guessed that this magic number related with one of SO' silver badge) just to earn the new pretty chevron.</sup>

Comment: Why are they "obsolete"? What's wrong with these tags?

Comment: Pardon for my English. This tags duplicates the main tag ([tag:jasper-reports])

Comment: It doesn't seem like a duplication. Rather, they just seem like *more specific* tags. What's wrong with that?

Comment: As I mentioned at post this classes are part of JasperReports API. It is a only a small part of a library. There are a lot of classes in this lib

Comment: Some times ago one guy added one of this tags to 50 questions just to earn the new badge (Taxonomist).

Comment: You might want to flag a post they've edited for moderator attention and explain the situation if someone's making superfluous edits, but I don't know that the tag themselves need blacklisting. I don't know what the community stance is on tags for specific classes but they certainly exist for other languages.

Comment: It is a past story. Several active users at [jasper-reports] tag are cleaning posts regularly. At the present moment there are no posts under this 2 tags. But today one of them were used again

Comment: @Cody Initially, I was going to use an example of a specific Java class that would be plausible but silly as a tag. Alas, every single one I searched for (`IOException`, `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer`, `ThreadPoolExecutor`, `SecurityException`) had a sub-tag so I guess there is plenty of precedent on SO for relatively useless sub-tags.

Comment: Burninate request denied, there's no pun in the title.

Comment: Hey Alex, I know you from some answers ago, great effort in supporting people who need help with Jasper Reports. I agree with your opinion regarding the tags.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Thank you Daniel :)

Answer (score 35):

These tags define a specific component in the [jasper-reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasper-reports) library and we can not have a tag for every class and component.

The [jasper-reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasper-reports) tag is already a low traffic tag and these additional random components tags only confuse users and are often used improperly which only create troubles to SO.

Conclusion, yes these tags should be removed and yes, yesterday I also cleaned the [jasperviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasperviewer) with some close voting and re-tagged where the question and answer to me seemed useful.

<sup>Note: The tag had around 17 question, so I felt no need to go to meta, but was doing my own burnation effort, passing some cv-pls in SOCVR</sup>

Should they be blacklisted, yeah that would be nice, if some SE staff have some time please do it, otherwise we will just need to continue randomly to clean it up.

Comment: Can't those tags just be made synonims? Did I misunderstand how tag synonims work?

Comment: I don't think blacklisting the tags is necessary since creating the tag after being burninated requires 1.5k rep already, unless it's a repeated case. Tag synonym might be a better idea.

Comment: We cleaned this tags several times before

Comment: @AndrewT. tag synonym in low-traffic tag is very difficult, the only 2 people here that could vote on it is me and Alex K and that's not enough... anyway surely it's not fundamental for SO to blacklist these tags we will continue to clean, it would just be nice, if some staff pass by and it's quick work for them